# Query, suma de columas con condiciones

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Muy buenas, ahora tengo un incoveniente con una consulta, lo que necesito hacer es una suma de la columna cantidad, y cantidad_dev, pero que esto se haga por cada cliente (no una suma de toda la columna).

A esta tabla es que necesito hacer el query, que sume por Id_cliente

```
CREATE TABLE `Movimientos` (
  `Id_control` int,
  `No_Pedido` int,
  `Id_cliente` int,
  `Id_producto` int,
  `Id_dev` int,
  `Cantidad` smallint,
`Cantidad_dev` smallint,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_control`),
  KEY `FK` (`No_Pedido`, `Id_cliente`, `Id_producto`, `Id_dev`)
);
```

Tengo esta consulta, pero no es lo que necesito

```
SELECT m.fecha, sum(m.Cantidad) as cantidad, sum(m.Cantidad_dev) as cantidad_dev
FROM movimientos AS m
```

Comment: Sumas por separado o en un solo resultado? Necesitas que aparezca el nombre del cliente?

Comment: ¿No te hace falta en tu declaración el indicar esas llaves foráneas con que columnas de las otras tablas se unirán?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar GROUP BY para agrupar por Id_Cliente y mostrar una suma para cada cliente. Fijate he recreado tu escenario y tengo la tabla Movimientos con 4 registros, dos registros para un cliente y dos registros para otro cliente de manera que podamos ver la suma

```
 SELECT * FROM Movimientos;
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado]

Ahora bien, agregamos el GROUP BY a tu sentencia SQL y vemos como se realiza la suma por Id_CLiente

```
  SELECT m.Id_cliente, sum(m.Cantidad) AS Cantidad, sum(m.Cantidad_dev) AS Catidad_dev
  FROM Movimientos m
  GROUP BY m.Id_cliente;
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado2]

Comment: Te agradezco grandemente, es lo que estaba intentando hacer.

Answer (score 0):

asumo que existe una tabla donde almacenas clientes, en ese caso puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT m.fecha, sum(m.Cantidad) as cantidad, sum(m.Cantidad_dev) as cantidad_dev FROM movimientos m, clientes c WHERE m.Id_cliente = c.Id_cliente;
```

Comment: Aunque funcional procura no usar una sintaxis de Join tan antigua

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo.